# Recover the package manager after crash during update

Tags: package-management

My so frequently crashing 12.04 system responded with a kernel freeze during my last package update. Which did result in malfunction Package Manger that describes the error as such: *"Error:BrokenCount>0"*...

Can the package manager be recovered in some way?

Comment: By package manager you mean apt-get?

Answer (score 2):

You might wanna try updating system from terminal
open terminal by

```
Ctrl+Alt+T
```

code:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade --fix-missing
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: It does always improve the quality of an answer to include some explanation and not just posting a single command.