# Crash During Update Deleted ALL panels; can't open terminal; can't see icons

Tags: command-line, updates, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recover the package manager after crash during update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173648/recover-the-package-manager-after-crash-during-update)

So I was upgrading Ubuntu from 11.10 to 12.04 in the terminal after recovering my system from a previous crash, and then I go through a power outage during the second time trying to update. NOW, my screen is white, only the time shows up in the top right corner, no icons show up, no apps show up, AND terminal is NOT opening. I can still use the internet somehow, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> opens what I think is a back-up terminal? NEED HELP to recover what is lost.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a live CD, you will be able to access to the content of your computer. In this case, you can still backup what can be saved, (re)install Ubuntu 12.04 from scratch and then put your backup on this fresh (and clean) install.

What you can see by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> is a command line interface. With this, you can only access to terminal functionnalities. You can attempt to launch the graphical UI by typing the `startx` command.

You can also do your backup like I explained below with the CLI but a basic knowledge of Linux commands is required - commands for moving (`mv`), copying (`cp`), deleting files and folders (`rm`), changing the current directories (`cd`) and seeing what is inside a directory (`ls`). If you do not feel confident with the CLI, consider using the live CD which is much more user friendly and which will not enable you to due errors due to the big power of commands.